# How to use base doubleclick event from one project to be used in other project?

Tags: c#, winforms

The project is very long so I will copy only this small part.

```
public MACTrackBar()
        {
            base.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseDownSlider);
            base.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseUpSlider);
            base.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseMoveSlider);
            base.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseDoubleClick);
         }
```

Then in the same project

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

After I'm making changes i build it and adding the dll file to my other project toolbox.
but instead doing it in the same project i want the event to be able to make it in form1 in my other project after adding the dll.

[image: The control in my other project dragged it form the toolbox]

Then in my other project in form1 i'm doing

[image: events]

but i don't see the new event the OnMouseDoubleClick i created in the source project.

maybe the MouseDoubleClick is the new event i created in the source ?
maybe i need to make it somehow public instead base  in the source ?

i'm a bit confuse. is the new event exist in the dll and can be used in the other project or the event is only available in the source project ?

In the source should i add the event like this

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                
            }
```

because if i don't make it in the source i will get error that the OnMouseDoubleClick is not exist and i want it to be in the other project to create the event in form1.

i checked again now this events are not exist none of them in the other project where i added the dll file and dragged the control.

```
base.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseDownSlider);
base.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseUpSlider);
base.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseMoveSlider);
base.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseDoubleClick);
```

so all this events are local to the source project.
how can i add a public event ?

when in the other project after dragged the control to the form1 designer i want that in macTrackBar1.
to be able to create the event for the double click maybe the name i gave to the event is wrong it should be something like

OnTrackerDoubleClick instead of OnMouseDoubleClick

the problem is how to be able to create the event in other projects ?

Updating on what i tried so far

In the source project i added event like this

```
public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> TrackerDoubleClick;
        
        public MACTrackBar()
        {
            base.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseDownSlider);
            base.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseUpSlider);
            base.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseMoveSlider);
        }
```

The line i added is

```
public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> TrackerDoubleClick;
```

then in the other project i did

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            macTrackBar1.TrackerDoubleClick += MacTrackBar1_TrackerDoubleClick;
        }
```

and for testing

```
private void MacTrackBar1_TrackerDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
```

but the double click is not working does nothing.

what i want to do is double click event on the tracker the blue circle thing.

[image: the blue circle thing the tracker]

and it should be in the source in the method

```
public MACTrackBar()
        {
            base.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseDownSlider);
            base.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseUpSlider);
            base.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler (OnMouseMoveSlider);
        }
```

and not outside like i did.

Comment: Your `private void OnMouseDoubleClick() ...` is not an event, it's the handler method of an event. To declare an event, add `public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> TrackerDoubleClick`, if you're using the default arguments. Call `TrackbarMouseClick?.Invoke(this, e);` to raise it -- See [event (C# reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) and [EventHandler Delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler) -- You shouldn't subscribe to events in your class, you should override the methods that raise the event.

Comment: You raise your public event when your Control calls its on `OnMouseDoubleClick` method (the method you should override). That is the method that raises the `MouseDoubleClick` event, when you call `base`. If you omit `base.OnMouseClick(e);`, the base class' event is not raised.

Comment: @Jimi i updated my question with some more information of what i just tried. but its not working as exepcted.

Comment: @jimi the event in the source should be inside the MACKTrackBar() method but in this method i cant declare public variables.

Comment: @Jimi here is the complete class code in the source project.  the method MACTrackBar() is at line 214 and the event line i added is at line 210. https://pastebin.com/GKxQ1jrN

Comment: Well, you have added your public event, now you have to override the methods that raise the base class events. Add `protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e) { base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e); TrackerDoubleClick?.Invoke(this, e); }`. Now, when you double-click on that Control, `OnMouseDoubleClick` is called and your event is raised. Do the same for other events if you want to provide a custom behavior.

Comment: @Jimi i still don't get it how the event in the source project will be double click with the mouse for the blue thing and not for the whole control it self ? i want the double click event to be for the blue thing only the blue thing you move along the slider and not the slider control it self.

Comment: The *blue thing* is most probably a graphic object, drawn in the position determined by the current value. When `OnMouseDoubleClick` is called, you can verify whether the location of the mouse pointer is inside that area and raise your event only when it is (i.e., when `TrackerRect.Contains(e.Location)`).